# NoSuchMethodError on VIew constructor

Tags: java, android

I'm instantiating a View at runtime, and 99,99% of the times works, but some users have reported that it crashes throwing a NoSuchMethodError.

I'm instantiating the View like this, and that's where the Error is thrown:

```
AddAPostView addAPostView = new AddAPostView(getContext());
```

And that's the code for the View:

```
public class AddAPostView extends LinearLayout {

    public AddAPostView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public AddAPostView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public AddAPostView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
      ...
    }
}
```

I've got the report through Google Analyics, so I only have the line in which the error is generated.

How is it possible that sometimes a code simple like that throws such a drastic Error? How to avoid that?

Comment: So... no stack trace?

Comment: I only have this: NoSuchMethodError (@NewFullscreenSocialHandler:createAddPostView:71) {main} (that's the line from which I instantiate my View)

Comment: It says [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html) that it may be that Class files were modified. Maybe those users are messing with them?

Answer (score 2):

What is your `minSdk`? If it's below 11 then bingo.

The three argument constructor was added in API 11. Even though you aren't using it, when the class is instantiated all methods need to be looked up and boom `NoSuchMethodError`

[image: 3arg constructor api 11]

[developer.android.com/LinearLayout.html#LinearLayout(android.content.Context)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#LinearLayout(android.content.Context))

( It will compile on your machine because of the `targetSdk` you set. )

Comment: minSdk is 14, that's not the problem

Answer (score 2):

`NoSuchMethodError` is usually an indicator that the code that you compiled with is using a different version of the class than the code that threw the error. In principle, the code wouldn't have compiled if it did not find the method at compile time. The fact that it compiled ok means that the method is there during compilation. Also, the fact that the code could not find the method at runtime means that it is using a different version of the class. I am more inclined to think that it is an outdated code issue, as you mentioned that only few of the users reported the error. They must be using some older version of your code or older version of dependent libraries.

Please verify that the users who reported this error have the latest copy of your code running. Also, the versions of dependent libraries should be same that you use for compilation. I am not an adroid developer, but I have seen similar cases all over Java world at many times and the root cause is always the version.

Comment: The class I'm instantiating always had that constuctor.

Comment: not necessarily the constructor. As I mentioned `All your code and all of dependent libraries` so if the constructor is calling another method in another class which is out of sync, you would still have NoSuchMethodError. Best way is to request the users to get the latest version of your app and try. If there are any external dependencies that your app needs, ask users to update those too.

Comment: To add, looking at Bundell's answer above, looks like the dependent libraries that I was mentioning may be of the Android SDK itself. So it may be the case that the users are using a different version than the version you are using for development. I would suggest going through the link in Bundell's response above. But this is certain that it is a version issue on the users' end.

Comment: @P.J is right, it seems one of your method calls has a `minSdk` that is higher than what you declare in your AndroidManifest `14` but because you target probably `18` you can't see it. **TIP** Change your `targetSdk` to `14` and you will get compile errors on any code that is not available in `14`